# Save merge conflict resolutions -- merging twice, staging then production

Tags: git, tfs, merge

Is there a way to save merge conflict resolutions?

Here's the use case. Save I have three branches: production, staging, and development. Development has a ton of changes. I want to merge dev into staging, and then use staging for testing. Whereafter, I will eventually merge staging into production.

- Production --> [branch] --> Development
- massive amount of changes to Development
- Production --> [branch] --> Staging
- Development --> [merge] --> Staging
- massive amount of testing
- Staging --> [merge] --> Production
- ready for release!

In this scenario, I will have to resolve the same merge conflicts upon each merge. Is there a way to save my resolutions?

Asking primarily for TFS version control, but will also accept git solutions for a matter of theory/terminology.

Comment: For Git, see `git rerere`: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html

Comment: Maybe you can branch Dev, Pro from Staging.Then develop in Dev branch--merge from Dev to Staging--test in Staging--modify in Dev Staging--test pass in Staging, merge from Staging to Pro. In this way, you should not have many merge conflicts.

Comment: When you merge Staging to Production just take the changes from Staging during the merge conflicts as there was no change in the Production branch after the development merged into Staging.

Comment: Which version control system are you actually using, centralized version control TFVC or  Distributed version control  GIT?

Answer (score 0):

According to `Asking primarily for TFS version control` assume you are using TFVC. If so, just change your branch hierarchy will save a lot of merge conflicts.

For now you are using:

```
Production --> [branch] --> Development
Production --> [branch] --> Staging
```

Actually there are no relation ship between Development/Staging these 2 branches, when you do the merge, it's baseless merging,  every single item will have a merge action and list in pending changes.

You should use below branch hierarchy

```
Production --> [branch] --> Staging
Staging --> [branch] --> Development
```

When you have massive amount of changes to Development, just merge back to Staging. After massive amount of testing, when the staging branch is steadily. You could merge back (`Staging --> [merge] --> Production`) to production branch.  There will not be many merge conflicts, when you have usually just select "keep the source version" option in diff tool. Finally ready for release!

This will save merge conflict resolutions in your case. For more info about Branching strategies, your could refer below two threads:

- [Branching strategies with TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/branching-strategies-with-tfvc)
- [Branch strategically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/branch-strategically)